# FullCalendar Resource AND Column Grouping

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am looking to implement the timeline view:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view

I want to have the rolled up grouped resource AND grouped columns at the same time.

It would look like this:

[image]

I can't seem to implement this - is it possible?

Comment: I can't see a way to make it do that, either. Maybe you could make a feature request to fullCalendar - there are instructions on the website.

Comment: Way ahead of you  https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a confirmed bug:

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5324